# SQL multiple tables one condition is inappropriate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql:

```
SELECT logins.*, users.*, invoices.number
FROM logins,
     users,
     invoices
WHERE logins.user_id = users.id
  AND users.id = invoices.userId;
```

This is simplified version of my statement. The reality is more complicated.

When

> users.id=invoices.userId

is false (because table invoices don't contain row with this userId) I need add to invoices.number=0.

Comment: You should switch to 'modern', standard, `JOIN` syntax, and it'll become a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join` to return rows even if no invoices are found.  For those rows, columns from the `invoices` table will be `null`.  You can use `coalesce` to return `0` instead of `null` in that situation:

```
SELECT  logins.*
,       users.*
,       COALESCE(invoices.number, 0) AS number
FROM    logins
JOIN    users
ON      logins.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN
        invoices
ON      users.id = invoices.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

use explicit join instead of comma separated join

```
SELECT logins.*, users.*, invoices.number
FROM logins 
join users on logins.user_id=users.id
join invoices on  users.id=invoices.userId;
```